# Position of struct in C

Tags: c, struct

To make my code as clear as possible, I am trying to do something like :

```
struct Test {
   int a; 
   int b;
   struct Test2 c;
};

struct Test2{
   int d;
};
```

Of course this code is wrong because `struct Test2` is used before being defined. I want to declare the struct forward. So I typed `struct Test2;` before `struct Test` but it didn't work. Is there a solution?

I know it is possible with functions, so maybe it should be the case for structures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that this is not possible is that when you place a concrete `struct Test2` object inside `struct Test`, you need to know the size of `Test2` to determine the size of `Test`. But you can't know the size without knowing the full definition first.

Forward declarations allow you to use a pointer to a type, since you can point to something without knowing the details until later. While it may not completely satisfy your needs, you *could* do something like the following with a forward declaration:

```
struct Test {
    int a;
    int b;
    struct Test2 *c;
};
```

The reason that a function declaration works is that it tells you everything you need to know about how to interface with the function. You don't need the function itself for that.

Answer (score 4):

It only works if `struct Test` holds a pointer of type `struct Test2*`.
If it holds an instance, `struct Test2` must be defined before `struct Test` because the size of `struct Test2` must be known.